# Web scrape a table created by a Javascript function

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, geckodriver

I am trying to scrape the table of research studies in the below link

https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?cond=COVID&term=&cntry=&state=&city=&dist=

The table has dynamically created content using Javascript.
I tried using selenium, but intermittently getting StaleElementException.
Please help me with the same.

I want to retrieve all rows in the table and store them in a local database.
Here is what I have tried in selenium

```
 import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
 url = 'https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?cond=COVID&term=&cntry=&state=&city=&dist='
 driver=webdriver.Firefox()
 #driver.implicitly_wait(30)
 driver.get(url)
 data = []
 for tr in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@id="theDataTable"]//tbody//tr'):
  tds = tr.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
   if tds:
    for td in tds:
     print(td.text)
     if td.text not in data:
      data.append(td.text)          
 driver.quit()
 print('*********************************************************************')
 print(data)
```

Further the data from the 'data' variable I'll store in DB.

I am new to selenium and Web Scraping and further, I want to click on each link in the 'Study Title' column and extract data from that page for each study.

I want suggestions to avoid/handle a stale element exception or an alternative for Selenium webdriver.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you check my answer? The code for me is working and collects all the data (all 1300 studies)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code of mine and all the data are stored properly. Can you try it?

**CODE**

```
driver.get("https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?cond=COVID&term=&cntry=&state=&city=&dist=")


time.sleep(5)

array = []

flag = True
next_counter = 0

time.sleep(4)

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('theDataTable_length'))
select.select_by_value('100')

time.sleep(5)

while flag == True:
    if next_counter == 13:
        print("Stoped")
    else:
        item = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("tbody")[1]
        rows = item.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')

        for x in range(len(rows)):
            for i in range(7):
                array.insert(x, rows[x].find_elements_by_tag_name('td')[i].text)
                print(rows[x].find_elements_by_tag_name('td')[i].text)

        time.sleep(5)
    next = driver.find_element_by_id('theDataTable_next')
    next.click()
    next_counter = next_counter + 1


    time.sleep(7)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1

Not yet recruiting
NEW
Indirect Endovenous Systemic Ozone for New Coronavirus Disease (COVID19) in Non-intubated Patients
COVID
Other: Systemic indirect endovenous ozone therapy
SEOT
Valencia, Spain
2

Recruiting
NEW
Prediction of Clinical Course in COVID19 Patients
COVID 19
Other: CT-Scan
Chu Saint-Etienne
Saint-Étienne, France
3

Not yet recruiting
NEW
Risks of COVID19 in the Pregnant Population
COVID19
Other: Biospecimen collection
Mayo Clinic in Rochester
Rochester, Minnesota, United States
4

Recruiting
NEW
Saved From COVID-19
COVID
Drug: Chloroquine
Drug: Placebo oral tablet
Columbia University Irving Medical Center/NYP
New York, New York, United States
5

Recruiting
NEW
Efficacy of Convalescent Plasma Therapy in Severely Sick COVID-19 Patients
COVID
Drug: Convalescent Plasma Transfusion
Other: Supportive Care
Drug: Random Donor Plasma
Maulana Azad medical College
New Delhi, Delhi, India
Institute of Liver and Biliary Sciences
New Delhi, Delhi, India
6

Not yet recruiting
NEW
A Real-life Experience on Treatment of Patients With COVID 19
COVID
Drug: Chloroquine
Drug: Favipiravir
Drug: Nitazoxanide
(and 3 more...)
Tanta university hospital
Tanta, Egypt
7

Recruiting
International COVID19 Clinical Evaluation Registry,
COVID 19
Combination Product: Observational (registry)
Hospital Lclinico San Carlos
Madrid, Spain
8

Completed
NEW
AiM COVID for Covid 19 Tracking and Prediction
COVID 19
Other: No Intervention
Aarogyam (UK)
Leicester, United Kingdom
9

Recruiting
NEW
Establishing a COVID-19 Prospective Cohort for Identification of Secondary HLH
COVID

Department of nephrology, Klinikum rechts der Isar
München, Bavaria, Germany
10

Recruiting
NEW
Max Ivermectin- COVID 19 Study Versus Standard of Care Treatment for COVID 19 Cases. A Pilot Study
COVID
Drug: Ivermectin
Max Super Speciality hospital, Saket (A unit of Devki Devi Foundation)
New Delhi, Delhi, India
```

My code is doing the following logic steps:

- First, I select the option to see 100 results and not 10 in order to save some time for retrieving the data.
- Secondly, I read all the results of the page (100) and when I finish I go to click on the next page symbol. Then I have a sleep command to wait for 4 seconds (you can do it in a better way but I did it like this to give you something fast -  you have to insert waitUntilElementIsVisible concept)
- After clicking on the next page button, I again save the results (100)
- This functionality will run until the flag is going to be False. It's going to be false when the next_counter is going to be 14 (more than 13 which is the maximum). Number 13 is actually 1300 (results) divided by 100 (max number of results per page) so 1300/100 = 13. SO we have 13 pages.

Editing and transferring the data is something that you can manage and there is no need for Selenium knowledge or something concerning web automation. It's a 100% Python concept.

Comment: Thanks @dpapadopoulos for the answer!
I tried this, but still getting Stale Element Exception

Comment: @Akshay Phadnis The StaleElementException occurs when the webelement is changed on the dom and the initial reference to that webelement is lost. So, please try the code again. I updated it.